# trying to compare a String to a Hashtable key/value

Tags: java, string, compare, hashtable, enumeration

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> coordinates= new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
String value = (String) cb1.getSelectedItem();
if(value==coordinates.keys())
```

It gives me a "imcompatible operand types String and Enumeration" error, any idea how I can compare these two without a loop?

Comment: @javaguy its a combobox:  final JComboBox<String> cb1 = new JComboBox<String>(Places1);

Comment: And then: you never ever compare strings using == you use the equals method instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply because a `Set` is a collection of `Strings`. Comparing would be like "I've got this bucket of apples and I got this apple, let's compare them". What you can do though is check whether the `String` is part of the `Set`, which is as simple as calling `coordinates.keys().contains(value)`.

And regarding the comparison:
Don't compare `Strings` using `==`. `==` compares by value, which would in case of `Objects` such as `Strings` be the reference. Use `string1.equals(string2)` instead. This topic is covered more extensively [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use the keySet method which will return a Collection. Then call contains on it with the selected value.

```
    Hashtable<String, Integer> coordinates= new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    String value = (String) cb1.getSelectedItem();
    if (coordinates.keySet().contains(value)) {
        //Some action...
    }
```